# C++ function call without enough template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, template-argument-deduction

When I was looking at https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/aten/src/ATen/native/RNN.cpp#L744, the function is declared to take 4 template parameters, but only 2 parameters are passed to the template when calling that function. Where does the cell_params and io_type come from in this case?

```
template<template<typename,typename> class LayerT, 
         template<typename,typename> class BidirLayerT, 
         typename cell_params, 
         typename io_type>
  std::tuple<io_type, Tensor, Tensor> _lstm_impl(
      const io_type& input,
      const std::vector<cell_params>& params, 
      const Tensor& hx, 
      const Tensor& cx,
      int64_t num_layers, 
      double dropout_p, 
      bool train, 
      bool bidirectional) {
    ...
}



auto results = _lstm_impl<FullLayer, FullBidirectionalLayer>(input, params, hx[0], hx[1], num_layers, dropout_p, train, bidirectional)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last two parameters are obviously deduced from function arguments. `io_type` from `input` and `cell_params` from `params`

Comment: When template is used explicit types should be provided only if can't be deduced or when you want force specific type.

Comment: @Lemon Have you never seen `std::swap` or `std::sort` or `std::make_pair`?

Comment: I am new to C++ and have encountered them before.